# easiest way to get path tag from user uploaded svg?

Tags: javascript, svg

User uploads a svg file with html input element:

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" accept="image/svg+xml" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

What do I put in the handleFiles function to read the path tag inside the svg. I don't care about displaying the image, I just want to read the path tag for its data. Any ideas?

EDIT:
So far I'm utilizing FileReader to get the image's data as follows:

```
function handleFiles(files){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var svgData = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}
```

Now how would I get a path tag out of svgData? Is this the best way to do it?

EDIT2:
Ok so I think I have a solution but it feels kind of hacky. It requires having an object tag with position:absolute; and opacity:0; because it won't load with display:none;. Here is the code:

```
function handleFiles(files){
    var obj = document.getElementById('svg-object');
    obj.data = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    obj.onload = e => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(obj.data);
        var path = obj.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];
        console.log(path);
    }
}
```

The previous code works, but is it the best solution?

Comment: You don't show any effort in researching this problem. Don't expect others to write you code for you. Have you even tried anything yet?

Comment: updated my answer with a solution, just not sure if it's the best solution...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I woud use the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

It parses html / svg / xml just like your browser would and returns a Document. In this case a SVGDocument because the MIME type is set to `image/svg+xml`.

```
function handleFiles(files){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var svgData = e.target.result;
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(svgData, "image/svg+xml");
        var pathTags = doc.getElementsByTagName("path");
        //Do whatever you want with pathTags
    }
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}
```

```js
//Example data
var svgData = 
`<svg class="icon  icon--plus" viewBox="0 0 5 5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M2 1 h1 v1 h1 v1 h-1 v1 h-1 v-1 h-1 v-1 h1 z" />
</svg>`;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(svgData, "image/svg+xml");
var pathTags = doc.getElementsByTagName("path");
console.log(`Found ${pathTags.length} path tags`);
console.log(pathTags);
```